# Is V a vector-space under this operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $V=\{(a_1,a_2): a_1,a_2 \in C\}$. For $(a_1,a_2), (b_1,b_2) \in V$ and $c \in C$, let's define

$(a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2)=(a_1+2b_1,a_2+3b_2)$ and $c(a_1,a_2)=(ca_1,ca_2)$

It's V a vector-space under this operations? Justify your answer.

My answer: We get that $a_1+b_1=a_1+2b_1$ and $a_2+b_2=a_2+3b_2$
Hence addition commutativity(VS 1) doesn't work, neither Associativity of addition(VS 2), and (VS 8), therefore V is not a vector-space under this operations.

Is this right or enough?

Answer (score 2):

Your way seems not correct, we can proceed as follows for $a \neq 0$

$$(a,a)+(-a,-a)=(a-2a,a-3a)=(-a,-2a)\neq (0,0) $$

Comment: In case it was not clear enough, $(a,a)+(-a,-a)=(a,a)+(-1)(a,a)=(0,0)$. Hence contradiction.

As for your answer, @MarioM21, in order to see its flaw, try to distinguish between $+$ for numbers and $+$ for vectors in writing.

Comment: I don't understand, I supposed addition of vectors was defined like $(a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2)=(a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2)$ .I'm not seeing how you adding the **a** vectors .

Comment: @MarioM21 We are considering the alleged vector space for the pairs $(a_1.a_2)$ with the sum defined by the rule indicated.

Comment: What does "considering the alleged vector space for the pairs $(a_1,a_2)$" mean? The sum defined by which rule?

Comment: @MarioM21 Let $V=\{(a_1,a_2): a_1,a_2 \in C\}$ ...such that $(a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2)=(a_1+2b_1,a_2+3b_2)$ is the alleged definition, but it doesn't works as vector spaece.